# How do I find which RTC module my kernel loads?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

During compilation of my kernel using a configuration file obtained from Ubuntu OS 16.04, I noticed I am compiling a lot of RTC drivers, basically every possible driver:

```
... snip ...
CC [M]  drivers/rtc/rtc-bq4802.o
CC [M]  drivers/rtc/rtc-da9052.o 
CC [M]  drivers/rtc/rtc-da9055.o
... more of those ...
...
```

I was wondering if could get rid of those many drivers, so I started looking around for how to:

1. looking in `lsmod` I see no RTC driver
2. `lshw` isn't helpful either
3. `lspci -v` also wasn't yielding much info.

Lower level inspection, shows a device exists:

```
$ ls -l /dev/rtc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Dec 18 09:54 /dev/rtc -> rtc0
```

The closest I got the get more info is in `/sys/class/rtc/`:

```
$ sudo cat /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/device/rtc/rtc0/name 
rtc_cmos
```

Doe that mean, that the only driver my kernel is using is `rtc_cmos`?

- Does that mean I do not need all the other drivers?
- Does that mean that my laptop uses a CMOS compatible hardware?
- also, why does `modinfo rtc_cmos` return nothing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does that mean I do not need all the other drivers?
>   Does that mean that my laptop uses a CMOS compatible hardware?

Exactly, if you only care about that RTC, then rtc_cmos is all you need.
rtc-efi is probably a valid alternative if your PC is recent enough.

> also, why does modinfo rtc_cmos return nothing?

Because the driver is probably compiled statically in the kernel instead of as a module. Check for CONFIG_RTC_DRV_CMOS=y in your configuration.

Comment: Yep! ```$ grep CMOS /usr/src/linux/.config
CONFIG_GENERIC_CMOS_UPDATE=y
CONFIG_RTC_DRV_CMOS=y
```

Comment: Is rtc-efi part of efi modules? I see `CONFIG_EFI=y` but I don't see anything with `grep CONFIG_RTC /usr/src/linux/.config | grep -i EFI`

Comment: Actually, it has been disabled on x86 since https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=7efe665903d0d963b0ebf4cab25cc3ae32c62600

Comment: OK, thank for letting me know. So, that means my kernel is using the GENERIC_CMOS driver. I re-compiled my kernel and un-marked the other drivers, so far the computer is working as expected.

Answer (score 8):

I understand the OP got the correct answers to the narrow question, but I feel it more in SO spirit to generalize the answer, so I am posting it in hope that it would be helpful to answer the generalized question: *How do I find what driver the `/dev/xyz` is using?*.

### Option 1: Poke the /sys filesystem

Provided you have `sysfs` mounted (normally at `/sys`; but I have yet to find out a distro that does not), why do not ask the kernel itself?

1. Find out the [device type (char/block) and the node number](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/devices.txt):

```
$ ls -l /dev/rtc0
crw------- 1 root root 249, 0 2019-04-01 15:22:29 /dev/rtc0
^                       ^   ^
+-> character device    +---+-> Major and minor node numbers.
```

2. Substitute the numbers into the /sys/dev path as below, (`char` is for char devices, `block` is, you guessed it, for block devices).

```
$ cat /sys/dev/char/249:0/name
rtc_cmos 00:00
```

This is the name of the kernel module that is attached to the node. Works same regardelss of whether the module is linked into kernel, or loaded via modprobe. (And `00:00` is not the time in the RTC clock. Rather, IIRC, it's the device address or "function" on its parent driver or bus; but do not trust me on this, I remember that only vaguely).

---

Side note, feel free to explore this filesystem. It's readable by non-root (except for security-sensitive parts, *most* of which you can read as root), entirely safe to read, and you can find a lot of hardware and low-level software configuration info there. Unlike most of `/proc`, most of `/sys` is writable, and used by programs to change the running kernel and device parameters. For one, sysctl works entirely through it. But I digress.

### Option 2: Have `udevadm` look under `/sys` for you

If you have udevadm available, ask it everything it knows about the device (the program accepts both `/dev` and `/sys` paths for the device):

```
$ udevadm info -a /dev/rtc0

[...snip intro text...]

  looking at device '/devices/pnp0/00:00/rtc/rtc0':
    KERNEL=="rtc0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="rtc"
    DRIVER==""
    ATTR{date}=="2019-06-27"
    ATTR{hctosys}=="1"
    ATTR{max_user_freq}=="64"
    ATTR{name}=="rtc_cmos 00:00"
    ATTR{since_epoch}=="1561605536"
    ATTR{time}=="03:18:56"
    ATTR{wakealarm}==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pnp0/00:00':
    KERNELS=="00:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pnp"
    DRIVERS=="rtc_cmos"   <== THIS
    ATTRS{id}=="PNP0b00"
    ATTRS{nvram}==""
    ATTRS{options}==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pnp0':
    KERNELS=="pnp0"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

The `info` command instructs udevadm to give out everything it knows about the device, and the `-a` switch is to go up the chain of parent drivers/busses. Here you see that the parent device `/devices/pnp0/00:00` has the driver `rtc_cmos`, and is discovered/activated on the bus created by another device, `pnp0`, which is the plug-and-play bus enumerator.

By the way, the names udevadm prints are also paths in the sysfs, i. e. you can see them in your normal file space by prefixing the sysfs mount point, `/sys`:

```
$ ls -l /sys/devices/pnp0/00:00/rtc/rtc0
$ ls -l /sys/dev/char/249:0/
```

Both these command will produce identical output.

Once caveat is, unlike "normal" file systems, sysfs *does* hardlink directories, so do not try to do any recursive searches in it (like `find . /sys` or `ls -R /sys`) -- these programs will just crash after struggling with the infinite looping over the filesystem.

### So what about the `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/device/rtc/rtc0`?

As you noticed, there are multiple paths from the root of sysfs down to the device parameter node. *Which one is the real McCoy?*

- Not every device has an interface via the `/dev` filesystem (or any other; there is nothing special about `/dev` -- it's just a tempfs; it's the *file* `/dev/rtc0` which is special). These you won't find through the path `/sys/dev/*`.
- Not every device is part of a subsystem, this is also optional. There are not discoverable through `/sys/class*`. So this is also a helpful, but optional link. Note that this node is different: it must expose subsystem-specific parameters. In our case, all RTC clocks expose a [well-known set of settings common to the `rtc` sybsystem](https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/omap/+/glass-omap-xrr02/Documentation/rtc.txt#138).
- Now, `/sys/devices/pnp0/00:00/rtc/rtc0` *is* the main, canonical path to the device sysfs node. It always corresponds to its topological location in the hierarchy of system busses and drivers: this is the instance `rtc0` of the device `rtc`, which is addressed as `00:00` on the bus `pnp0`. It does not always correspond to its physical connection; in our case, `pnp0` is a virtual bus which does not connect devices to physical busses and bridges, but only discovers and enumerates them. This is the canonical name for the device (sans the `/sys` prefix, of course--it's just a mount point) used by udev to uniquely identify it.
- Finally, a kernel module does not have to expose *anything* in sysfs. Only the modules that must be discoverable from userspace need that, strictly. But if it does, the module decides *what* to expose, and it's parent and grandparents determine *where* in sysfs it will be under the `devices` root.